# Unable to properly render a triangle in SDL2 (MAC M1)

Tags: c++, macos, sdl

I'm trying to render a triangle using SDL2 on my MAC (M1), however, the triangle i'm able to generate is too much pixellated and unnecessary pixels are being rendered.

Output:

[image]

My Code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // returns zero on success else non-zero
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {
        printf("error initializing SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    SDL_Window* win = SDL_CreateWindow("GAME",
                                       SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                       SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                       900, 900, SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI);
    if(!win)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create window\n";
        return -1;
    }
    
    int *w_t = new int ();
    int *h_t = new int ();
    
    SDL_GetWindowSize(win,w_t,h_t);
    
    std::cout<<"width:"<<*w_t<<"height:"<<*h_t;
    
    SDL_Renderer* brush = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, 0);
    
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(brush, 255, 0, 0, 0);
    SDL_Point a = {0,500};
    SDL_Point b = {800,500};
    SDL_Point c = {250,250};
    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event e;
    while (!quit) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(brush, a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y);
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(brush, a.x, a.y, c.x, c.y);
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(brush, b.x, b.y, c.x, c.y);
        SDL_RenderPresent(brush);
    }

 
    return 0;
}
```

- OS: macOS Monterey
- IDE: Xcode
- Compiler: Clang

Comment: Anything change if you clear the renderer each frame?  Which renderer backend is in use?  Anything change if you choose a different backend?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the SDL renderer; usually I drop directly into Vulkan or OpenGL when using SDL -- but I can at least say that it's a reproducible issue on my M1 Mac from this minimal example. That's trippy though; I get a lot more squares along the draw-lines

Comment: @ genpfault i am purely using SDL2 and have tried the SDL_Clear() function, however using that colors whole of my window.....

Comment: @Human-Compiler, so i should use SDL only for events looping ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing the renderer before drawing the lines:

```c
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(brush, 0, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
SDL_RenderClear(brush);

SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(brush, 255, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE); 
SDL_RenderDrawLine(brush, a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y);
SDL_RenderDrawLine(brush, a.x, a.y, c.x, c.y);
SDL_RenderDrawLine(brush, b.x, b.y, c.x, c.y);
SDL_RenderPresent(brush);
```

Comment: Can confirm that this seems to fix the graphical artifacts. Why does this make a difference though? Since the frame is unchanging, I would expect clearing the renderer to be unnecessary for a still image like this.

Comment: @Human-Compiler even if you initialise backbuffer once (or twice, in case of double buffering), there is no guarantee contents of backbuffer would persist after `SDL_RenderPresent` (and documentation explicitly says so), unless rendering backend used by SDL provides that guarantees.